# F# array sum can't print

Tags: f#

So far, I have pretty much things set but that dumb printfn is still not working.

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let n = Console.ReadLine() |> int
    let nums = seq { for i in 1..n -> Console.ReadLine() |> int }
    printfn "%d" (Seq.sum nums)
    0
```

Comment: put a 0 at the end?

Comment: main needs to return a int, and printfn is unit I think

Comment: 0 fixed the error but for some reason, the array sum still isn't working. I have a warning that says "line (8,9) the result of this expression is implicitly ignored. Consider using 'ignore' to discard this value explicitly, e.g. 'expr |> ignore', or 'let' to bind the result to a name, e.g. 'let result = expr'."

Comment: Please do not edit your question that much, especially not by adding answers. This makes the answers disconnected and less useful. Instead ask for clarification in comments to answers. Consider reverting to revision 2. What you could do instead is adding the screenshot to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from Joseph explains what is wrong with your code.

If you wanted to do this in a more F# way, then you'd probably want to eliminate the mutation altogether. One reasonably nice way of doing this would be to use sequence expressions to construct a sequence of all the numbers that you're reading from the console and then use `Seq.sum` to calculate the sum:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let n = Console.ReadLine() |> int
    let nums = seq { for i in 1..n -> Console.ReadLine() |> int }
    printfn "%d" (Seq.sum nums)
    0
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately the print is still not working. I mean, everything should be set except for printfn.

Comment: according to you sample input. All input numbers are expected in the second line. So your code is blocking in `Console.ReadLine()`

Comment: @AlexZhuravel according to your code all numbers need to be on separate lines

Answer (score 1):

Two things I noticed, you need to end the program with 0, that is the exit code.
Second thing is the equals sign in FSharp isn't used for updating values, F# uses the <- operator instead. Here is your program with the updated changes.

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let mutable sum = 0
    let n = Console.ReadLine() |> int
    for i in 1..n do
        let mutable r = Console.ReadLine() |> int
        sum <- sum + r;
    printfn "%d" sum
    0
```

Comment: Thanks, no more warnings nor errors, but the array sum isn't still working for some reason. Like it's not printing out a value.

Comment: Are you running this in a .fsx file or a fs file?